# Jquery mobile 1.4.5 & cordova app facebook comments

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, facebook-comments

I have build a Jquery mobile hybrid app via cordova 5.4.0 and I want to know if there is a way to incorporate a facebook comment box inside my app pages.
Can someone point me to a direction?
Thank you